# Linux Mint/Ubuntu - hybrid graphic card drivers (AMD® Radeon HD 8570 + Intel HD Graphics 4000)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, hybrid-graphics

I've read almost every topic on every discussion board, blog posts etc. about my problem. I've tried many tips, but nothing seems to work. I've even changed Linux distribution from Ubuntu to Mint, nothing.

I'm trying to install drivers for my **hybrid graphic card**. Right now I have default drivers (*xserver-xorg-video-ati*) but there is major problem with that. When I try to open few tabs in my browser (Chromium/Firefox) everything is slowing down and I have to wait until somehow it unfreezes itself.

Installing fglrx or fglrx-update crashes my system. I really don't know what to do, I don't want to go back to Windows 7.

My laptop parameters:
**Lenovo Essential G500H i3-3110 4GB 1TB HD8570**:

- Intel® Core™ i3 3gen 3110M 2,4 GHz
- **AMD® Radeon HD 8570 + Intel HD Graphics 4000**
- 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz

Any help?